# The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resources'

Tags: xml, spring-mvc, xsd

This is my spring-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
        <mvc:resources mapping="/CSS/**" location="../CSS/" />
        <mvc:resources mapping="/scripts/**" location="../scripts/" />
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.zensar.controllers" />
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>
      </beans>
```

and web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID"   version="3.0">
        <display-name>SpringMvc</display-name>
        <welcome-file-list>
          <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
        <servlet>  
          <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
          <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
          <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
      </servlet>  
      <servlet-mapping>  
          <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
          <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
      </servlet-mapping>
      </web-app>
```

After running my project I am getting an error:

> The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resources'

Comment: Why don't you add your pom so we can see the spring jar's you are using

Comment: What is it you don't understand?  You have a schema; it has a strict wildcard; an element in your instance matches that wildcard, but the validator can find no declaration for that element in your schema.  Possible causes include failure to load the schema you think you're loading, failure of the namespaces on the element instance and element declaration to match, and misspelling of the element name in declaration or instance.   Without a minimal complete reproducible example, no one can help you figure out which of these applies.

Comment: i didn't have pom.xml . its simple mvc project . i am new in this technology . will you elaborate what i have to do. i want to upload .css and .js files .

Comment: in web.xml when i change <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> to <url-pattern>*.html<url-pattern> it works. please guide me i am still facing problem.